# Mongodb database tool commands wont take effect

Tags: mongodb

I want to use commands such as mongodump/mongorestore/mongoexport on my local windows computer and have therefor downloaded the .msi extension version of mongodb database tool and also executed the .msi so it could be installed.

But what do i do now to start using the commands. I cant find any documentaions of this. Is there something i have to configue?

When i execute a command like mongodump on my system command line i get the response:

```
'mongodump' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Do i maybe have to execute the command from a certain dir location?

Comment: Did you add the installation path of that tools to your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: No i have not. How do i do that?

Comment: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/ perhaps a re-login is necessary to apply the changes

Comment: re-login of what? what do you mean by that? do you mean restart the computer?

Comment: Logout and login of your user. Dude, your are trying to use mongodb and dont know what i mean with "re-login" ?!

Comment: still get the same response from the terminal

Comment: How does your `PATH` var look like ? What did you add, wher did you install the mongo tools ?!

Comment: here is my PATH var:  https://gyazo.com/ba82f45e3e636b42de9bcecb3994fcfa

Comment: i have also tried 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Look for the highlighted folder on your system. When you install the database tools this folder is created. Inside this folder there is a `bin` folder which contains all the commands you are looking for.

[image]

- Once you find this folder then navigate to bin folder. And open a command prompt at that location. And try running the commands.

[image]

**Alternatively:-**

You can set `PATH` to `bin` folder and then you will be able to run the commands from anywhere.

Comment: My structure in mongodb program file looks abit different sense i used the .msi extension version which automatically installs the 'mongo database tool' look at the link below to se the gif: https://gyazo.com/bd3263ae7fa8dc69f2ab5f4576706bdd

Comment: Go to Program->MongoDb->Tools->100->bin and open command prompt there. Then run the commands.

Comment: It may be beacuse of location. Just try by copying the `Tools` folder in some other drive(except C drive)